# Prev Next Navigation in Slide

Tags: javascript, css, navigation, slider

[image]

The Concept is a Slide with the prev & next images visible with low opacity.
There are Arrow keys to navigate the slide left & right with pagination buttons.

This is the structure of the HTML I have with me right now. I came across a tutorial on the net.(you might have to copy paste the file on your HTML editor software for the JavaScript to work) 
http://jsfiddle.net/Doodle/yTrWP/1/ (source code) 
 
http://www.temzlemdor.in/stackoverflow/coolcarousel.html (working page)

but I am Missing out on the arrow keys. 
can someone help me out on that.

Another one i'm working on is this. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Doodle/pyqhg/ (source code) 
 
http://www.temzlemdor.in/stackoverflow2/coolcarousel.html (working page)

[image] [image] 
(for prev/next images) 
Here I am Missing out on the side images getting low opacity. 
Any assitance on how i can get these fixed to my concept? 
I'm a newbie to javascript

Comment: Your fiddles don't seem to work and they look nothing like your image above.  If you want more people to play around with them and offer you help, you should probably simplify them and, of course, get them to exhibit the issue you want help with.

Comment: @Nick G, i apologize for that. I have updated the question.
the links in jsfiddle are for the source code. it will have to be compiled in an HTML editor to work. 
this is for the working page. 
1st eg: http://www.temzlemdor.in/stackoverflow/coolcarousel.html 
2nd eg: http://www.temzlemdor.in/stackoverflow2/coolcarousel.html

Comment: I am really wondering what you mean by `to be compiled in an HTML editor`.

Comment: Ok...Js fiddle has four slot, one for HTML,Javascript,css & the result.
the source code i gave has javascript integrated on the html page also...so it wont run in jsfiddle....so it would have to be put in an HTML editor software like Visualstudio or Dreamweaver with the script links & css to work.
. I really apologize for that.

Comment: I gave the working links of the concept to get an idea of my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer from here.... >br/>
http://fiddle.jshell.net/JCQ6Q/15/show/ 
Gee....its like I asked the question & I happened to answered it myself... :D